# How to move an element on ready without blinking

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to scroll a `div` (`content`) as soon as the item (`scan`) in the `div` is ready. It works fine, but `scan` still flashes up for a part of a second.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('scan')).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('content').scrollTop = 60;
});
```

Is there a way to move/scroll the item without showing?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: I don't get it working properly in fiddle but it looks like [https://fiddle.jshell.net/dffn8aL6/1/](https://fiddle.jshell.net/dffn8aL6/1/).